# Shortest hyperpath algorithm in intuitionistic fuzzy hypergraphs

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, algorithms, hypergraph

I was looking for an algorithm to calculate **the shortest hyperpath in intuitionistic fuzzy hypergraphs** and I found only [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/256720925_Intuitionistic_fuzzy_shortest_hyperpath_in_a_network) article (which propose two algorithms).
Are there any others algorithms that serves the same purpose ?

In the meantime, I was trying to find a way to implement this algorithm using a programming language (such as Scala, java or python) but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Hi Bilal, I think the second half of your question belongs more to StackOverflow, and there you might also get an answer for the first half as well. Good Luck

Comment: Ok @AmirSagiv, how can I migrate the question to stackoverflow ?

Comment: I don't think you should. Leave it here, post another one on SO, and link the two.